# Mapping user id onto a dict comparing to see if user is already in dict

Tags: python, xml, loops, python-2.7, dictionary

I have code which currently prints out data for each user from an XML file (obtained from a website) the XML updates as more users interact with it throughout the day. I currently have my code looping to download this data every 5 minutes.

Every time the code is ran it generates a list of users and their statistics, 
 first 5 mins  it prints users: z,y,z

second 5 mins it prints users:

```
x,y,z,a,b
```

third 5 mins it prints users:

```
x,y,z,a,b,c,d
```

What I need the code to do it to print first 5 mins:

```
x,y,z
```

second 5 mins:

```
a,b
```

third 5 mins:

```
c,d
```

Some how recognising that some of the users have already been used. Each user does have a unique user id which i guess could be matched?

I enclose an example of my code, in case that helps.

```
import mechanize
import urllib
import json
import re
import random
import datetime
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

######Code to loop the script and set up scheduling time

s = scheduler(time, sleep)
random.seed()

def run_periodically(start, end, interval, func):
    event_time = start
    while event_time < end:
        s.enterabs(event_time, 0, func, ())
        event_time += interval + random.randrange(-5, 45)
    s.run()

###### Code to get the data required from the URL desired
def getData():  
    post_url = "URL OF INTEREST"
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

######These are the parameters you've got from checking with the aforementioned tools
    parameters = {'page' : '1',
              'rp' : '250',
              'sortname' : 'roi',
              'sortorder' : 'desc'
             }
#####Encode the parameters
    data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
    trans_array = browser.open(post_url,data).read().decode('UTF-8')

    xmlload1 = json.loads(trans_array)
    pattern1 = re.compile('>&nbsp;&nbsp;(.*)<')
    pattern2 = re.compile('/control/profile/view/(.*)\' title=')
    pattern3 = re.compile('<span style=\'font-size:12px;\'>(.*)<\/span>')



##### Making the code identify each row, removing the need to numerically quantify the     number of rows in the xmlfile,
##### thus making number of rows dynamic (change as the list grows, required for looping function to work un interupted)

    for row in xmlload1['rows']:
        cell = row["cell"]

##### defining the Keys (key is the area from which data is pulled in the XML) for use in the pattern finding/regex

        user_delimiter = cell['username']
        selection_delimiter = cell['race_horse']


        if strikeratecalc2 < 12 : continue;

##### REMAINDER OF THE REGEX DELMITATIONS
        username_delimiter_results = re.findall(pattern1, user_delimiter)[0]
        userid_delimiter_results = (re.findall(pattern2, user_delimiter)[0])
        user_selection = re.findall(pattern3, selection_delimiter)[0]



##### Printing the results of the code at hand

        print "user id = ",userid_delimiter_results
        print "username = ",username_delimiter_results
        print "user selection = ",user_selection
        print ""





    getData()


    run_periodically(time()+5, time()+1000000, 3000, getData)
```

I have been informed that this can be achieved using quote: "a dict that maps user_id onto the object containing user's data. On each run of the scraper, check if user id is already in the dict, and if so update the corresponding object, otherwise add a new entry to the dict." If anyone could provide some example code for such a problem, I will be able to engineer it to work for a solution for my code.

Kind regards and many thanks
AEA

Comment: easiest thing would be to keep a list of all user ids and if the id already exists, don't print anything.

Comment: @FMc Hey FMc, I have been trying my hand at this python coding for a cumulative 12 days, I am afraid without some sort of example to work to  or reverse engineer, i dont have a clue where to start! :s          Kind regards AEA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to keep track of the `user_id`s you've already output in a list, but it might be easier to just remember the position in the list you last left off--that is, if you've already output the first 5 users on previous runs, start with row number 6 on the next run.  You could implement that in your loop like:

```
#outside of the run loop
number_output = 0

#in the run lop
for row in xmlload1['rows'][number_output:]:
    number_output += 1
    cell = row["cell"]
```

The only problem with this would be if users could be duplicated in the input file and you do not want to output the second instance of a user.  In that case, it would be best to use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).  Then, each time you output a user, add its username to your set like

```
my_set.update(username)
```

and check if the user has already by output with

```
if username in my_set:
    ...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply Michael, however the list is sorted by ROI this means that any new users registering their data, could replace the user who is row 3. e.g 3 users resisted so far, with ROIs of 5% 10% & 12% these users will be listed  row 1 12% row 2 10% row 3 5%. Upon a second scrape of the xml, a user has registered his data with an ROI of 7% he will be input into row three displacing the old user in row 3. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @AEA, if the users are not ordered, then an approach using a `set` (the second half of my answer) would be appropriate.  This approach is similar to your suggestion of using a dict, but more memory and time efficient.